# Makefile Compile Error and Visual Studio Code did not recognize include files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I use visual Studio Code and gcc-12.1.0, x86_64-w64-mingw32 and SDL2.

I have folowing Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ -I scr/include -L scr/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

If I only have one main.cpp comiling and everything works. But now I added Header files and other C++ files. But I see already in Visual Studio Code that the Include .cpp and .h are getting an error that the file is not found.
But the Files in die Directory and same project as main.cpp

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdTZq.png)

What do I have to change or what I´m doing wrong?

BR druckgott

Comment: Are you using the MakeFile tools extension?

Comment: `-I scr/include` is relative to the current working directory which could be anywhere.  Try with an absolute path to check the issue and then workout where VS Code sets the current working directory when building.

Comment: What is the error message? It's always helpful (to you and to future askers searching for it) to include the error verbatim in the question in plaintext.

Comment: I think the complaint is the red squiggle but it should be better explained in the question. Also remember that Intellisense is an IDE feature that is totally independent from building. And it's designed to give a fast answer which may be wrong some of the time. In this case its likely wrong because of a configuration issue but we can't see the configuration.

Comment: Yes I use MakeFile Tool extension
SDL Lib is working, but all my other cpp and header files are not working

`PS F:\CPP\03_Testgame_SDL2> make
g++ -I scr/include -L scr/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
In file included from main.cpp:1:
MSController.h:5:10: fatal error: MSGameWindow.h: No such file or directory
    5 | #include <MSGameWindow.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1`
also if i use `#include "MSGameWindow.h"` its not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

g++ should be able to handle it, but for local includes you would usually use `#include ""` not `#include <>`. Otherwise, try to compile manually from the command line and see if the issue is related to your makefile / vs-code or if the include really can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

It was my makefile, now it works:

```
all:
g++ -I scr/include -L scr/lib -o main main.cpp MSController.cpp MSGameWindow.cpp MSEventHandler.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```